# Why doesn't the parser wait for Promise.resolve?

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, promise, use-effect

I am using React and I do not understand why in the useEffect when running a map function the second part of the code runs before the first part (which is a promise resolve).
Shouldn't the parser wait for the promise to resolve and then run the second part of the code?

```
  useEffect(() => {

    const pools = mainnet.Exchanges.Pancakeswap.LpTokens.map((lpPool) => {
        // part 1
        const [tokenZeroSymbol, tokenOneSymbol] = lpPool.name.replace(' LP', '').split('-');
        const prices = fetchTokenPrice(tokenZeroSymbol.toLowerCase(), tokenOneSymbol.toLowerCase());
        Promise.resolve(prices).then((values) => {
          const [priceTokenZero, priceTokenOne] = values;
          filteredFarmPools.find((pool) => {
            if (lpPool.name.replace(' LP', '') === pool.name) {
              pool.priceTokenZero = values[0].usd;
              pool.priceTokenOne = values[1].usd;
            }
            console.log('inside the fethcprice promise');
          });
        });


        // part 2
        filteredFarmPools.find((pool) => {
          if (lpPool.name.replace(' LP', '') === pool.name) {
            const tvl0 = (pool.reserveTokenZero / 10 ** 18) * pool.priceTokenZero;
            const tvl1 = (pool.reserveTokenOne / 10 ** 18) * pool.priceTokenOne;
            pool.tvl = tvl0 + tvl1;
          }
          console.log('inside the tvl calc');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Promises give you an object that you can pass around and call `then` on.

They do not turn asynchronous code into blocking code.

---

The second part of the code isn't inside the `then` callback so it runs while the asynchronous code (that will trigger the first promise to resolve) is running in the background.

---

That said, see [the `await` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) for asyntax that can give the illusion that a promise is blocking.

Answer (score -2):

```
useEffect(() => {
    const processPools = async () => {
        for (let lpPool of mainnet.Exchanges.Pancakeswap.LpTokens) {
            const [tokenZeroSymbol, tokenOneSymbol] = lpPool.name.replace(' LP', '').split('-');
            const values = await fetchTokenPrice(tokenZeroSymbol.toLowerCase(), tokenOneSymbol.toLowerCase());
            // Promise.resolve(prices).then((values) => {
            const [priceTokenZero, priceTokenOne] = values;
            filteredFarmPools.find((pool) => {
                if (lpPool.name.replace(' LP', '') === pool.name) {
                    pool.priceTokenZero = values[0].usd;
                    pool.priceTokenOne = values[1].usd;
                }
                console.log('inside the fethcprice promise');
                // });
            });
        }
    }

    processPools();
});
```

1. Original Array.map does not support async
2. Promise.resolve return immediately, no difference with Promise.then